# Make setxkbmap preferences being set at startup

Tags: startup, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to switch left Ctrl key with caps permanently. But with ubuntu native keyboard layout switcher xmodmap did not persisted ([this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407652/ubuntu-13-10-resets-key-map-loaded-with-xmodmap-when-switching-keyboard-layout)). So now i just ditched native switcher and using setxkbmap command instead. I created a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,ru -option grp:alt_shift_toggle -option ctrl:swapcaps
```

It works just as I want to. But now i want to auto run it on system start up. But if I put this under Sturtup Applications it does not work. Apparently something else resets xkb map after my script at start up.

Does anyone know what triggers reset of xkb and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Could you try run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` to make these changes system wide.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Finally, after much research here's what I found for ubuntu 13.10:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
$ dconf-editor
```

navigate to org >> gnome >> desktop >> input-sources

Put your options under xkb-options as a list. Ex: ['altwin:ctrl_alt_win','..etc..']

Then close the dconf-editor. Changes should come live straight away.

... I'd post a screenshot but my reputation on this board isn't high enough, please gimme some points ;)

Ref:

- [How to permanently switch Caps Lock and Esc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc)
- man 7 xkeyboard-config

Comment: Still works on Unity on 16.04. Thank you!

Comment: this is single user only and is gnome only.

Comment: @RichieHH yes. I did not want to modify the mapping for other users.