# Why does this command doesn't run at startup

Tags: startup-applications

So I want to turn capslock into ctrl. From my google-fu the command to run is `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"` and it works when I run it at the terminal. But when I place it on 'Startup Appliacations' the command fails to take effect. Any idea why?

Comment: This is wrong way to set xkb settings anyway. The proper way is to use `xorg.conf`. (i.e. `Option "XKbOptions" "ctrl:nocaps"`.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make setxkbmap preferences being set at startup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/410499/make-setxkbmap-preferences-being-set-at-startup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On recent Ubuntu versions there's a dconf option (*if you are using GNOME or Unity*):

```
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

which you can set via dconf-editor or gsettings. For example,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['ctrl:nocaps']"
```

This option is permanent across reboots.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put this `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"` command on startup applications.Hust place it inside `~/.bashrc` file.

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add this line to the `.bashrc` file,

```
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"
```

Logout and loginback to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but I am curious why it is Startup Applicaions not working as intented.