# Permanent Changes to xkb-settings (12.04)

Tags: unity, gnome, keyboard

I am able to remap <kbd>caps lock</kbd> to be an extra <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key by running the following:

```
setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"
```

However, as discussed in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446835/why-does-this-command-doesnt-run-at-startup/446839#446839), the changes are not persistent (also after any lock, such as suspend). The first answer is not helpful, because I want the change all the time, not necessarily after I've opened a terminal (unless Ubuntu sources .bashrc on login?)

The second answer seems to be what I want, but the referenced `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` doesn't exist for me.

Is there somewhere else in dconf editor (or elsewhere) to set this so it is permanent?