# Remapping Caps Lock in 14.04 Trusty Tahr

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout

I've seen a number of questions that point to a GUI menu to remap caps lock, but that menu seems to be gone in 14.04. Am I just not finding it, or is it really gone? I know you can use `xkbmap` to remap it, but I'm not really sure how to make that persist.

**Edit**

I've tried the suggestions on the accepted answer for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys), but nothing seems to be working. From what I can tell, the `.xinitrc` file doesn't ever seem to be sourced. Is there some other work around that might fix this for me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remap certain keys?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys)

Comment: @Jobin if you'll notice I'm asking specifically about 14.04, not just in general.

Comment: Have you tried the solution? I see that you have specific doubts as to whether it will persists reboots and that question address that concern.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I swap Escape and Caps Lock?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/444714/how-do-i-swap-escape-and-caps-lock)

Comment: It looks like Ubuntu 14.04 uses ~/.xsessionrc instead of ~/.xinitrc

Answer (score 27):

You should edit the file **/etc/default/keyboard**
and modify the XKBOPTIONS setting.

For example to map capslock to control set **XKBOPTIONS=“ctrl:nocaps”** (source: [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Swapping_Caps_Lock_with_Left_Control)

log out and log in again for changes to impact your system.

Comment: huge thanks mate, all this GUI nonsense with installing packages is a pain in the butt, and most ways either didn't work, or worked in some contexts but not others.

Answer (score 18):

Finally found a GUI answer, after much Googling: [How do I swap Escape and Caps Lock in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444714/how-do-i-swap-escape-and-caps-lock/446725#446725) (Looks like your question was phrased better and so showed up much higher in my search results.)

From the linked answer:

> Install the **GNOME Tweak Tool** (gnome-tweak-tool), under the *Typing* tab there is an option to swap <kbd>Esc</kbd> with <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. This worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04.

Strangely, the tool window's background didn't fill in for me, so I had to open up a gedit window behind it just to view the text.

Hope that helps! Even with the buggy window, it was much more pleasant than messing with xkb settings directly.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work under XUbuntu 14.04.

Comment: I got this to work in Ubuntu 14.04.  The window background bug is really bad - hard to believe nobody has fixed that.  If you want to swap CTRL and CAPS, that is done under "Ctrl Key Position", and is not available under "Caps Lock Behavior".  I was puzzling over why every other option for the caps lock was listed except for swapping with CTRL when I finally noticed the separate setting for CTRL.

Comment: Unfortunately **GNOME Tweak Tool** seems quite bugged when used in Unity. The solution using /etc/default/keyboard seems more appropriate (I tried both).

Comment: ```gnome-tweak-tool``` works well under Ubuntu 16.04.  I like that changes are effective immediately with no restart or anything.

Answer (score 8):

In my case the following worked to disable capslock in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:none
```

*Startup Applications* > *Add* > *Name*: Disable Capslock > *Command*: setxkbmap -option caps:none > *Add*.

Restart and capslock is disabled.

---

To remap capslock to escape key:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:escape
```

Comment: this is the simplest solution i could find and it works, setxkbmap -option caps:escape

Answer (score 3):

After searching around enough, I think I finally found that magic google incantation to find the answer. Here's the post that solved my problem: [Make setxkbmap preferences being set at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410499/setxkbmap-on-startup-in-ubuntu-13-10). I just followed the instructions in the accepted answer and added 'ctrl:nocaps' to the xkb-options. I really hope they just bring back the settings GUI to change this....

Comment: Unfortunaltely, now the capslock works as another CTRL-key. The capslock-key is not fully disabled.