# there is another way to change multiple resolutions in linux without wait to the login

Tags: login, xrandr, startup-applications, sh

I have already make a script doing this and i put it in the start app applications, but these commands only start when you login, there is a another way to do it when the computer turn on, or something like that when the grub inits?
I am using Ubuntu desktop 18.04

This is the script:

```sh
xrandr --newmode "1600x900R"   97.50  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 903 908 926 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "1600x900R"
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode "1600x900R"
```

[image]

Comment: can you search for posts like "how to run script before login"

Comment: The X Server starts after login. Before then, nothing will be listening for X-related commands.

Comment: i research and i put the scrip en .bashrc but this doesn't work because every time i open the terminal the script executes.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: ubuntu desktop 18.04

Comment: If you were on LightDM, there's a nice way in https://askubuntu.com/a/934797/158442. Not sure of GDM has an equivalent way

Comment: this post doesn't work

Comment: i dont know what is exactly lightDm and GDM