# Ubuntu 19.04 - How to enable Scroll Lock key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 19.04

I'm somewhat new to Ubuntu, and trying to get everything set up the way I like. On other OS's, I use Scroll Lock to turn down system volume, but I am unable to do so because Ubuntu doesn't recognize the Scroll Lock key as well. I've been looking around for solutions, but since xmodmap no longer works, I've been unable to find an up to date, permanent solution.

Comment: xmodmap works for my 19.04   I disabled the capslock key as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/574208/deactivate-caps-lock-in-14-04

Comment: xev in terminal can be used to determine the keystroke. so consider using xmodmap to enable if it doesnt show. you'll need to get the keycode of scroll lock