# Redefine Caps Lock key. Which configuration file to use for saving change permanently?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout

I am following [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/hacking-your-linux-keyboard-xkb)<sup>1</sup> tutorial about remapping keys in Ubuntu. The tutorial describes how one can remap the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key using `setxkbmap`. Currently I only want to test this by disabling the Caps Lock key:

```
setxkbmap -option "caps:none"
```

which works fine. However, it does not store the change permanently. After rebooting, the change is lost. The tutorial recommends to use a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-keyboard.conf` and enter a `InputClass` section:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "no,us"
        Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
        Option "XkbOptions" "caps:none"
EndSection
```

However, on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine there is no file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-keyboard.conf`.

After further googling, I got more confused, as there seems to be wide variety of answers and corresponding recommended files to use. For example, these file have been mentioned

- `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`
- `/etc/default/keyboard`
- `/etc/default/console-setup`

What is the correct way to do this on Ubuntu 16.04?

See also:

- [Remapping Caps Lock in 14.04 Trusty Tahr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453793/remapping-caps-lock-in-14-04-trusty-tahr)
- [How can I remap keyboard keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys)

**Edit:**

Creating a new file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-keyboard.conf` as suggested by @GunnarHjalmarsson in a comment, does not work either. However, I tested now setting the option in `/etc/default/keyboard` instead:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="no"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="caps:none"
```

and this seems to work fine! It would be nice if someone could also explain why?

**Footnotes**:

<sup>[1] [Hacking Your Linux Keyboard with xkb](https://www.linux.com/learn/hacking-your-linux-keyboard-xkb)</sup>

Comment: I suppose that the tutorial meant to say that you can **create** a `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-keyboard.conf` file.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes of course! Thanks. But unfortunately it did not work. After rebooting, the Caps Lock is still enabled.

Comment: I was about to suggest `/etc/default/keyboard`, and then saw that you already had made it work that way. Don't have a good answer why it works other than the file seems to be central for keyboard configuration on Ubuntu. Available options can be found via `man xkeyboard-config`.