# Where is keyboard extra settings menu?

Tags: keyboard

Where is this menu in original Ubuntu ? I got used to it with KDE. I miss it. Really.

[image: Keyboard extra menu]

Please, no alternatives. I want **that menu exactly**

Comment: Can't you just have numlock on?

Comment: I don't care about numlock. I want Apple support, euro sign, compose key on my right Cmd button, different shortcuts to switch to different layouts, X server reboot hotkey, and many thing. Don't tell me now about `xorg.conf`, OK?

Comment: Well that is quite a lot of things. Could you not just use OS X? You seem to want to make ubuntu into osx, which is a lot of work. And if the answer is xorg.conf, what should I say?

Comment: Okay so this http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys and this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey and this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=188761 should help.

Comment: This menu exists in Gnome2, Gnome3, KDE and XFCE. I just want to know where is this menu in this stub of DE people call Unity.

Comment: If you son't like it, use gnome? it might be in unity tweak tool, but I don't think it's there by default. A rant a unity won't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Current state of the keyboard extra settings menu**

It's a shame you already put a bounty on your question because it looks like a duplicate. Check these out:

- [How to use Alt+Shift to switch keyboard layouts?](https://askubuntu.com/a/419266/81372)
- [How to access the Keyboard Layout Options in 13.10+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360378/how-to-access-the-keyboard-layout-options-in-13-10)

Seems like this menu was still accessible in Ubuntu 12.04 but then scrapped and reimplemented as part of GNOME's ongoing effort to "simplify" things.

As pointed out in the answers I've linked to, there are several bug reports concerning the removal of these settings, [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1245064) being the most prominent.

Apparently some, but not all, of the missing settings have been moved to `gnome-tweak-tool` (*typing* section), so you might want to check that out to see if the options you're looking for are there.

`gnome-tweak-tool` is part of the official repositories and can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

---

**Workaround using `setxkbmap`**

*Overview*

With that said:

The keyboard options in Ubuntu and GNOME are nothing but a frontend to the X keyboard extension (XKB). If you are fine with configuring things manually you can easily reenable all of the now-missing options with a `setxkbmap` command line.

*Anatomy of a setxkbmap command*

You can supply `setxkbmap` with several options at once. A very simply command to set two keyboard layouts (Russian, English) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as their toggle would look like this:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle -layout ru,en
```

You can chain different options by separating them with a comma. What follows is a setxkbmap command that sets up the same keyboard layouts as above, adds <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> as a level 3 modifier, and assigns the `compose` key to right <kbd>Super/Win</kbd>:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle,compose:rwin,lv3:ralt_switch -layout ru,en
```

*Available options*

There are a multitude of options controlled by `setxkbmap`. All of these are documented in the XKB base settings list. This file should be available on your system under `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`.

If you look through it you should be able to find all of the options equivalent to the settings removed by GNOME.

The various XKB settings are also documented under `man 7 xkeyboard-config`.

---

**Alternative to setxkbmap**

If `setxkbmap` doesn't work for you, you can try setting the XKB options through `dconf` instead:

1. Install `dconf-editor` (`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`)
2. Open dconf editor from your dash and navigate to *org* → *gnome* → *desktop* → *input-sources*
3. Add your XKB settings to `xkb-options` in form of an array. E.g.: `['grp:alt_shift_toggle','compose:rwin','lv3:ralt_switch']`

Source: [Make setxkbmap preferences being set at startup](https://askubuntu.com/q/410499/81372)

Comment: Yes, I have seen these settings in gnome tweaks. These are just not the same. I shall wait for someone who knows how to restore that menu exactly. Since it is the same in all normal DE I presume it is some sort of component.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino I've added a section on manually configuring all the missing settings via setxkbmap, which might work on your system.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino There is no way to "restore it exactly". It was completely scrapped. I know, it was a bad idea.