# How can I make backspace repeatable after swapping it

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I just swapped <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> by adding `'caps:backspace'` to the `xkb-options` in `dconf-editor`. It works, but <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is not repeatable now, it only deletes one char and stops. How can I fix this?

I've read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74904/how-can-i-swap-capslock-for-backspace).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I added `'caps:backspace'` to the `xkb-options`.

Comment: It does not swap the keys, but makes Caps Lock an additional Backspace. I just tried it, and for me (on Ubuntu 17.10) both keys work as Backspace usually does. I can't reproduce the issue you describe.

Answer (score 1):

`xmodmap -e "clear Lock"`

The creator of the thread had mentioned this in an edit and it worked for me.
I am unable to understand how this works exactly but it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1269705)